# Internet connection fast in safe mode and slow in normal mode - Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, windows-8.1

I'm running a Toshiba Satellite C50D-A-12V laptop with Windows 8.1 with 8GB RAM. Anti-Virus is AVG Free, also have Malwarebytes and Spybot installed as well as CCleaner.

I have a 70mbps internet connection setup, and until recently was getting a steady 50mbps connection over Wi-Fi and 70mbps connection cabled to the router.  My cabled connection recently dropped to 10mbps and so my ISP (Virgin Media) came round and fitted a new super hub.  My tablet, phone and spare laptop connecting via Wi-Fi all get top speed connections, but this laptop when in normal mode only gets about 2.5mbps download but somehow gets 5mbps upload (both cabled and wireless).  That is the correct upload speed, so something is blocking my download speed.  Of course if I boot into safe mode, I get full speed again.

I have been scouring the internet and tried every answer I could find to resolve this issue:

- msconfig - Hid all MS Services and disabled the rest, no effect
- Startup list in Task Manager - Disabled everything and rebooted. No effect.
- Setup and tried a different Admin account and Standard account, as well as trying the actual Administrator account - same issue
- Tried all three browsers installed (Chrome, Firefox and IE - no toolbars) - no effect
- Updated all outdated drivers (only originals were installed prior) - no change
- Ran a clean boot - no change
- Ran full anti-virus and 2 malware scans - found some slight issues, but no change
- Have made sure both 2.4 & 5ghz wireless connections have different SSIDs, and even disabled one - no change
- Ran CCleaner and deleted all crap & temp files - no change
- Ran flushdns and the reset of TCP/IP - no change
- Checked network use in Task manager - nothing hogging it
- Checked Remote Procedure Call (RPC) and Security Accounts Manager Service were running - no change

That's just about every solution I've found so far, none of which have worked.  I have no P2P service running.  The only programme I have opened to connect to the internet is each browser individually.

I'm tearing my hair out trying to find a solution with the hope that it won't be to reinstall my OS.  Any help you could offer I'd appreciate.

Dak.

Comment: Did you try another antivirus software? Maybe some antivirus software which can be started from a bootable device without booting Windows (like Kaspersky Rescue Disk)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I do know it's not AVG that's causing the error.  I did manage to disable it and it also made no difference to the speed, but I'll look into your suggestion in the morning.

Comment: Have you tried using [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902)? It has a more extensive list of what runs (or is supposed to run) on startup than both msconfig and Task Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have been using Autoruns this morning.  I ran a comparison between startup programmes in both normal and safe modes, matched the normal mode items to the safe mode items, but unfortunately no change in download speed.

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Windows Task Manager and checking if any programs running under normal mode but not under safe mode are using a large fraction of the CPU time or a large fraction of the memory?

Comment: One of the first things I did, yes.  Unfortunately no joy.